# Update result wanted

Tags: c++, mongodb

I am updating a collection:

```
conn->update("mycollection", BSON("_id" << ID), BSON("$set" << BSON("myfiled" << myvalue)));
```

Is there a way to know if the collection was really updated or not? The function "update" is void and there is no exception has been thrown.
The function GetLastError returned empty string even if no data has been written to db.

Comment: Can you tell us what library conn is from? We can't help you if we don't know the details of the functions you're using.

Comment: conn is standard mongo::DBClientConnection *

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From MongoDB documentation :

> Write concern describes the guarantee that MongoDB provides when
>   reporting on the success of a write operation. The strength of the
>   write concerns determine the level of guarantee. When inserts, updates
>   and deletes have a weak write concern, write operations return
>   quickly. In some failure cases, write operations issued with weak
>   write concerns may not persist. With stronger write concerns, clients
>   wait after sending a write operation for MongoDB to confirm the write
>   operations.

I didn't use C++ driver but in Java driver there is a [WriteConcern](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.11.3/) class that lets you to control the operation. You can check for the equivalent class in C++ driver.

For more about Write Concern check [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/write-concern/).